# iOS save array status

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I have an iOS App that has a tableView which retrieves the data from a server in JSON format.
Then I have a modal view with another tableview that shows categories for the user to select which options they want to see in the previous screen.
I save the categories retrieved in an array - *categoriesArray.

I filter the array of categories into a new dictionary as follows:

```
filterDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
             for (int i=0 ; i<[categoriesArray count] ; i++) {
                 [filterDictionary setObject:@"true" forKey:[categoriesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
             }

             NSLog(@"FilteredDict is: %@", filterDictionary);
```

This works ok.
When the user selects a row, I change the Object to false, to know whether I should show that category or not:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if ([[filterDictionary objectForKey:[categoriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] isEqual:@"true"]) {
    [filterDictionary setObject:@"false" forKey:[categoriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else {
    [filterDictionary setObject:@"true" forKey:[categoriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}}
```

My problem is, when I dismiss the modalView, if I enter again, everything starts as if it was the first time, so everything is set to true, as it has to retrieve again the list of categories. How can I "save" the selection and check that it has been selected before if nothing has changed in the JSON retrieved?

I´m not sure if I´m explaining myself correctly...
Sorry if so, I´ll try to be clearer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on the amount of JSON data you could use Core Data to archive non-volatile saving on the disc within a sqlite db. On the other hand there's the option to (ab)use NSUserDefaults for small amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

When you dismiss a modal view controller, it is deallocated unless you keep a strong pointer to it, so when you "enter it again", you're going to a new instance, not back to the one you were in before. You should create a strong property for that controller in the controller that presents it. Before you do the presentation, check to see if that controller exists, if not create it (this will happen the first time you present it) then present it, if it does exist, just present it.